# How to rewrite url for certain pages in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to show different url and redirect users to specific url with .htcaccess when they click on a blog post but to no avail.

Lets say the url is: `http://localhost/mySite/article.php?article_title=test-title`

then I would like to show it as `http://localhost/mySite/article/test-title`

This is my current htcaccess file:

```
#turn on url rewriting
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#rewrite rule for blog
RewriteRule article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) /mySite/article.php?article_title=$1
```

But for some reason it is not redirecting/showing the correct url. I am not getting any errors.

---

### EDIT

Trying to ask my question again and explain it better. Let's say the url is

```
http://localhost/www.example.com/admin/editUser.php?user_id=126
```

and I would like to rewrite the url like this:

```
http://localhost/www.example.com/admin/user/126
```

then how can I achieve this. I tried using [this](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) website to check the modified url but it does not work. Seems like it does not work with any of the accepted answers here in stack at all.

This is my htaccess file atm. It is in the root of www.example.com

```
#turn on url rewriting
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ /editUser.php?user_id=$1 [NC,L] # Handle user edit requests
```

Apache Module mod_rewrite is enabled. Also added an alias. Still no changes in the url. If I try something really basic like this:

```
# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

it works fine.

Why is the users redirect not working? What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this for your rule for article url in mysite directory.

```
RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ article.php?article_title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

you need to mention start `^` and end `$` of string.

Comment: trying now. second

Comment: for some reason. it dosn't change the url. no errors as well

Comment: Okay i am assuming you are using this rule in your mysite directory with your above written rules. what happen when you use the above rule page loads or blank page occur.

Comment: blank page such as no content inside?